# Search with regex but replace only a portion of the string with sed

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to replace any occurrence of a `cwe.mitre.org.*.html` (regex) URL and remove the `.html` extension and not change any other type of URL.

Example:

```
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/377.html
http://google.com/404.html
```

Expectation:

```
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/377
http://google.com/404.html
```

Is there a way to do this in sed or another tool?

I've tried `sed -Ei 's/cwe.mitre.org.*.html/<REPLACEMENT>/g' file.txt`, but that won't work. Is there a way for the `<REPLACEMENT>` to be a regular expression? The [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) manual doesn't seem to suggest that?

EDIT: I was wrong about the sed manual. It does mention it, see "5.7 Back-references and Subexpressions" section of https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\(cwe\.mitre\.org.*\)\.html/\1/' file
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/377
http://google.com/404.html
```

google sed capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `AWK` solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/377.html
http://google.com/404.html
```

then

```
awk '/cwe\.mitre\.org.*\.html/{sub(/\.html$/,"")}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/377
http://google.com/404.html
```

Explanation: If you find provided regex in line, replace `.html` followed by end of line (`$`) using empty string. Every line, changed or not, `print`.

(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sed -Ei 's/(cwe\.mitre\.org.*)\.html/\1/' file
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cwe                      'cwe'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mitre                    'mitre'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    org                      'org'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  html                     'html'
```

The `\1` backreferences the part of a string captured by parenthesized piece of the pattern. When you want a piece of a match stay in the result, use the backreference.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is

```
% sed '/cwe\.mitre\.org/s/\.html//' try.txt 
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/377
Nothing
hello.html
http://google.com/404.html
```

This isn't unequivocally better than the accepted answer (it would get confused by `foo.html text http://cwe.mitre.org/bar.html`, for example, but the other answers may also be assuming there's only one relevant URL on a line).  I mention it as a supplement to that one, however, since it usefully illustrates that sed commands can be prefixed by ‘addresses’, which can include regexps.  This script deletes `.html` on any line which includes `cvw.mitre.org`.

This feature is often forgotten, and is only occasionally useful, but when it's appropriate, it can avoid an otherwise complicated regexp in the `s` ‘pattern’ slot, and back-references.